# Asynchronous conditional component rendering in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to set up a frontend authentication system in my RN app but I am having issues rendering either the auth views or main app views.

The root navigator is what renders either the auth views or main views, and I have a variable `signedIn` to check to see if the user is signed in or not

```js
const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

async function RootNavigator({ signedIn }: { signedIn: boolean | undefined }) {
  if (!signedIn) {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthenticationNavigator} />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="NotFound"
          component={NotFoundScreen}
          options={{ title: "Oops!" }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="NotFound"
          component={NotFoundScreen}
          options={{ title: "Oops!" }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }
}
```

The signed in variable is passed through my main navigation function

```js
export default function Navigation({
  colorScheme,
  authStatus
}: {
  colorScheme: ColorSchemeName;
  authStatus: boolean | undefined
}) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      theme={colorScheme === "dark" ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}
    >
      <RootNavigator signedIn={authStatus} />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And finally the authStatus variable comes from my main app function

```js
export default function App() {
  const isLoadingComplete = useCachedResources();
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const [checkAuth, setCheckAuth] = useState(false);
  const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(false);

  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Roboto_100Thin_Italic,
    Roboto_400Regular,
    Roboto_700Bold,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchToken() {
      try {
        const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('access_token');

        if (token) {
          setSignedIn(true);
        } else {
          setSignedIn(false);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      } finally {
        setCheckAuth(true);
      }
    }

    fetchToken()
  }, [])

  if ((!isLoadingComplete || !fontsLoaded) && !checkAuth) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
    return (
      <SafeAreaProvider style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <PersistGate persistor={persistor} loading={<AppLoading />}>
            <StatusBar style="auto" />
            <Navigation colorScheme={colorScheme} authStatus={signedIn} />
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm currently getting a typescript error in the RootNavigator

```
'RootNavigator' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'Promise<Element>' is not a valid JSX element.
```

And when I execute the code I am getting this error in the console

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_U, _V, _W, _X}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Comment: Why have you declared `RootNavigator` as an async function? I suspect changing it to a normal function will resolve the typescript error and the execution error as well.